# Graph API direct message for page: how to retrieve link to attached file

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message, attachment

I need to store the link to a file attached to a direct message (for a page, retrieved with "`/conversations`"). How can I do that?

I know how to get the link of an image. The JSON-object for an image ("`attachments`") contains the tag "`image_data`", which contains the tags "`url`" and "`preview_url`" for accessing the image.

For attached **files** (in my case e.g. a PDF), FB only sends "`id`", "`mime_type`", "`name`" and "`size`", but no additional data. Example:

```
"id": "m_id.158623824339344"
 ....
"attachments": {
    "data": [
     {
        "id": "7b84fd4c0f18fb4060ae0fe0dcfeb42e",
        "mime_type": "application/pdf",
        "name": "Attachment1.pdf",
        "size": 80798
      }
    ]
 }
```

But when I log into FB as a user and click the attachment in the browser, I get this link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id=<attach_id>&mid=id.<mid>&pageid=<pageid>&ext=<ext>&hash=AQCafpYeZj2pSjRk
```

By trial and error I found out that it is possible to access the file without the "`hash`" and "`ext`"-part. This means that in theory I am able to generate this link in my application ("`attach_id`" and "`mid`" are provided with the message and I know my pageid).

But this seems to be very unreliable. This link might change anytime, breaking my application.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any documentation about this. Does anybody know a better solution? Or can someone point me to some documentation regarding this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Barbara

Comment: I did the exact same thing. It appears that Facebook returns a blank page when you try to access an attachment when not logged in. So that's at least one use case in which this fails..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not available as of v2.5.

If this becomes a new feature in the future, you should be able to find it in the documentation:
https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/message/attachments